# If then else in json

Tags: json

Set values based on the ip address in JSON with if the else
Using perl JSON module.

I'm trying to setup my etc/config.json so that I never have to edit it when I move code from development->staging->production.
sql ip addresses will be different for different VM's

```
{
  "html_title" : "Bogus",
  "local_ip"  : 
  "default"   : "[production]",
  "hosts" :
  {
    "production" :
    {
      "10.11.12.13" : "b102-vm",
      "10.11.12.14" : "b103-vm"
    },
    "stage" :
    {
      "10.11.12.15" : "b102-vm-s",
      "10.11.12.16" : "b103-vm-s"
    },
  },
  "production" :
  {
    "some_schema" : 
    {
      "host"       : "10.11.12.13",
      "database"   : "some_table",
      "dsn"        : "DBI:mysql:[production.some_schema.database]:[production.some_schema.host]",
      "user"       : "user",
      "pass"       : "pass"
    }
  },
  "stage" :
  {
    "some_schema" : 
    {
      "host"       : "10.11.12.16",
      "database"   : "some_table",
      "dsn"        : "DBI:mysql:[stage.some_schema.database]:[stage.some_schema.host]",
      "user"       : "user",
      "pass"       : "pass"
    }
  },
  "if" :  HERE IS WHERE I GET LOST.
  {
    "local_ip" : {
    "anyOf"  : ["[hosts.production]"]
  }
},
  "then" : { "default" : "[production]" }
  "else" :
  {
     "if" :
     {
        "local_ip" : {
        "anyOf" : ["[hosts.stage]"]
      }
  },
  "then" : { "default" : "[production]" }
}
```

}

Would like to see "default" point to the production or stage values

Comment: What kind of technology is this configuration file for? Your question seems like it's about that technology, and not about JSON. JSON is a serialisation format. It's for data. You can't program in it.

Comment: JSON is not a programming language. It is storage format. I think you need to *generate* a different JSON file for each environment. You can do that using a Perl script.

Comment: JSON does not support the features required to achieve what you want by itself. You would need a post processor of some sort. Since you haven't identified any post-processor, we can't help you craft the config file so that it complies with the grammar expected by the post-processor. Voting to close as unclear due to this missing information.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, JSON is not a programming language; it is a data storage format.

I can think of two obvious ways to do this. Yours is, I'm sorry to say, not one of them.

Both of my solutions involve your various systems having an environment variable set which identifies the kind of environment it is. I'm also going to assume some kind of `get_config()` function that reads a config file and returns a Perl data structure of the config.

**Solution 1: Separate files**

Have two files called "staging.json" and "production.json". The `get_config()` function reads the required one.

```
sub get_config {
  my %valid_env = (
    staging => 1,
    production => 1,
  );

  die "$ENV{ENVIRONMENT} is not a valid environment type\n"
    unless $valid_env{$ENV{ENVIRONMENT}};

  my $json = read_file("$ENV{ENVIRONMENT}.json");

  return JSON->new->decode($json);
}
```

As an extension to this, you could have three files - `common.json`, `staging.json` and `production.json`. You'd always read `common.json` along with the correct environment file and merge the two data structures into one before returning the data.

**Solution 2: Munge the config**

Stick with your existing file but munge the data structure after you've read it and before you return it.

```
sub get_config {
  my %valid_env = (
    staging => 1,
    production => 1,
  );

  die "$ENV{ENVIRONMENT} is not a valid environment type\n"
    unless $valid_env{$ENV{ENVIRONMENT}};

  my $json = read_file('config.json');

  my $config = JSON->new->decode($json);

  # Use $ENV{ENVIRONMENT} to munge the contents of $config
  # so it only contains data about the current environment

  return $config;
}
```